# Android make an HTTP Get request through jsp to oracle db?

Tags: android, oracle, http, jsp

So I want to communicate with an OracleDB through my Android app. Allowing users to update the tables in the DB from their mobile phone.  Currently this application is running in desktop form using a JSP file.  I want to transition this JSP file to work with Android.  I've read I could connect directly to the OracleDB although this is not generally acceptable for obvious security reasons.  My question is could I use the existing JSP file with android and interact with the server through that? How would I make a GET request to the JSP file so I can call upon certain info to be downloaded from server and populate fields in my app? Thank you.

Comment: On [androidsnippets](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http+get+site:androidsnippets.com) there are several examples how to send a HTTP GET request. See also the large list of similar questions below *Related* column on the right hand side of this Stackoverflow page.

Comment: But it is possible to make a get request to a jsp file in android?  Sorry I am completely new to JSP...

Comment: Just replace the URL in the code examples by the one to your JSP... I'd however strongly recommend to use a servlet or a webservice which returns JSON or XML instead since that's easier processable than a bunch of HTML as JSP usually returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'd drop the JSP and look at a Web Service to the database through the Apex Listener.
Examples [here](http://krisrice.blogspot.com/2010/10/restjson-access-to-your-data-in-2.html) and [here](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/apex-listener-resource-templates/)